# Is it possible to stop traffic from specific ios ports using MDM

Tags: ios, mdm

Is there anyway to block the use of certain ports from the use of an ios MDM like jamf?  Say that you wanted to stop VPN's from being allowed?  Short of blocking every downloadable VPN from the app store, is there a way to prevent users from using these specific ports on their ios devices without closing off ports via a firewall?

Originally I was thinking about an apple app store keyword based block, but the Jamf MDM doesn't allow this.

Comment: No, there is no firewall/packet filtering capability in MDM profiles. You could use per-app VPN to direct traffic from managed apps through your own VPN or periodically examine the app inventory from managed devices looking for vpns

Comment: would you be able to block specific VPN apps from being downloaded by users.  As there are a few VPN's that override the settings of my VPN, and then utilize the downloaded vpn's software

Comment: It is possible to block certain applications from running - not from downloading.